# Ubuntu Mail Server issues... can send cant recieve

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email

I recently set up a mail server using

- Ubuntu 10.04
- Postfix
- Courier IMAP

Mail client is "Apple Mail"

I was recently having issues sending mail via port 25 but I could receive email fine.

To resolve that, I changed the port to 587 by modifying my Postfix **master.cf** file from:

```
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
 smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
```

To:

```
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
#smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
587        inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
```

Sending now works from the mail client, but I can't receive email now. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the server cannot receive incoming messages other than from the client? Your change disabled the smtpd listening on port 25 ("smtp") but enabled the submission port (which is 587, so you could/should use the last line instead). These two listeners are not mutually exclusive--uncomment them both and see what happens.

Comment: Your the man!, yeah, that was the issue. Thanks a lot.